# Cronjob won't run 80% of the time

Tags: ruby, linux, raspberry-pi, cron

I have a raspberrypi setup with emulation station and retropie. I have a cronjob set up so I can send myself an email at 8am everyday written in ruby. This script has worked effectively 100% when I first set it up but ever sice I upgraded my raspberrypi to the newest version of retropie and emulationstation, the cronjob has stopped work 80% of the time.

```
0 8 * * * ruby /home/pi/Facebook/facebook.rb
```

Is what it is currently. It worked yesterday.

I've tried these methods as well:

```
0 8 * * * 'ruby /home/pi/Facebook/facebook.rb'

0 8 * * * /bin/bash ruby /home/pi/Facebook/facebook.rb

0 8 * * * /bin/bash 'ruby /home/pi/Facebook/facebook.rb'

0 8 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby /home/pi/Facebook/facebook.rb'
```

I am not sure what the -l and -c is supposed to mean. However this one worked all the time when I had it set up before upgrading. Is the pi skipping the job at 8am or doing another job at that time which causes it to miss it? Or is it my script which may take forever to send the email via ruby to my gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Usually cron sends a error mail to the owner of the crontab, so check that owner's emails on that machine.

It is most likely a problem with the cron environment. Cron uses its own environment when starting jobs.

Comment: The weird thing is that when it was wrong it emailed me but most of the time it doesn't because it runs. I just don't know I guess if my script times out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the cron job is running your script, but your script may be erroring-out or timing out.  You might want to add some logging to your script, so you can see where the problem is.

Comment: I gave that a shot so we are gonna see what happens tomorrow. I tried a different version of the mailing procedure in ruby instead!